# Transimpedance Amplifier: Silly question that's killing me

Tags: operational-amplifier

I'm having huge trouble with this problem, I've probably done it 10 times already and there must be something that's slipping my attention.

The givens are:
\$I_{PMT}\$ = 150.0 pA, R1 = 73.0 MΩ, R2 = 2.0 kΩ and R3 = 200.0 kΩ.
What my calculations have been:

V+ = 0 so V- (at U1) is also zero. The equation at the node entering V- :

\$\frac{(0-V_O)}{R_1} + I_{PMT} = 0\$

which gives:
\$V_o = -I_{PMT} * R_1 = -73*150*10^{(-12+6)}\$
in the other input node entering V- of U2:

\$\frac{(0- V_O)}{R_2} + (0 - V_{out})/R3\$

which gives:
\$V_{out} = 73*-150*10^{(-4)} = -1095 mV\$

Someone help!!!

Thank you :)

[image]

edit1: by V_o I mean the voltage at node after R1 and before R2- the node output for the first op-amp

Comment: So, what is the problem?

Comment: i get the wrong answers :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your math seems to work out for me, though you're missing the inversion in the second section.

Try breaking the schematic up into two complete sections, and solve them independently.

\$V_o = I_{PMT} * R_1 = 73,000,000 * 0.000,000,000,15 = 73 * 10^{6} * 150 * 10^{-12} = 0.01095 V\$
at the point you're calling \$V_O\$ (e.g. the output node of U1).

Your second-stage gain is: \$V_{gain} = -\frac{R3}{R2} = -\frac{200k}{2k} = -100\$

your output voltage will be \$0.01095 * -100 = -1.095V\$

Your problem seems to be that you forgot that the inverting amplifier, well, inverts. You need to multiply your output voltage by -1.

Silliness: [Wolfram Alpha page for the calculation.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%2873*10%5E6%20*%20150*10%5E-12%29%20*%20%28-1%20*%20%28200/2%29%29)

---

Further verification - I stuck the circuit in the falstad circuit simulator. It's an ideal-circuit simulator, so it's not great for real-world analysis, but you're evaluating this circuit with ideal op-amps anyways, so that's not a problem.

[image]

At this point, if you're still getting an answer that is "incorrect" (I assume this is homework), you either have a typo somewhere, or the "correct" answer is actually not correct.

Comment: is your solution in V?

Comment: if yes then I have gotten the same solution too, and it's not accepted as right :(

Comment: @user65165 - Yes, it's in volts.

Comment: then, what's wrong????

Comment: i was asked in milliVolts that's why my response was -1095mV

Comment: @user65165 - In the question, you say 1095 mV, not **-** 1095 mV. Why are you certain this number is not correct?

Comment: oh damn, that must have been a typo. sorry

Comment: So, yes, it was a HW question, however I talked with my TA today and he said that I was right, so... probably some mistake in the "correct" answer